# To disable direct access to microservice & allow only though api gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, api-gateway, spring-cloud-feign

I am currently working with spring boot micro services. To access those services I am using api gateway with Eureka client but I have one question to secure my service.

Consider I have below 4 microservice project hosted locally.

1. User :- hosted on http://localhost:8080/user
2. owner :-  hosted on http://localhost:8081/owner
3. security :- hosted on http://localhost:8082/security

and api gateway :- hosted on http://localhost:9090/

so now to access services of owner I am first calling api gateway than security project after authenticating it is allowing me to access service of owner project .I am calling owner project from security project using feign client.

api gateway ---> security ---> owner

using url http://localhost:9090/security/owner

I am able to access owner project using that flow but now my question is **I am also able to call directly owner project using it's own port**. As shown below:-

http://localhost:8081/owner

**How can I restrict that direct access to owner project?**

Comment: How  and where is it hosted. If hosted on tomcat, you can configure tomcat in such a way that it will accept only local host requests for port 8080, 8081 and 8082. You can configure spring also to accept only connections from localhost. Only pre-requisite is that they all should be hosted on same server

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be for `owner` service to expect some kind of access token within the request. Such a token should be provided by `security` service (i.e. it could inject it within `Authorization` header), when it forwards request.

In more complex environment, in which multiple services may required different level of access to other services, more sophisticated solution would be required, i.e. involving mutual TLS where each service has its own certificate. But that would require much more setup. However that's worth doing on complex production systems.
One more element that could be used to control such access is the service mesh. You can read up on the topic - example: Istio.